# Can I operate IndexDb in the webwork?

Tags: indexeddb, webassembly

I follow this [webassembly cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Caching_modules). However, when I did this operation in the webwork, I got

> DOMException: Failed to execute 'put' on 'IDBObjectStore': An object could not be cloned.

Can I use indexdb to cache the webassembly module in the webwork?

Comment: Sorry, Maybe I Missed something. Now, I test it successully

Comment: I find the flag in chrome is

      " WebAssembly structured cloning support", you can find in "chrome://flags"